# Why anchor is not showing the hand cursor?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Following on from my last question. I now have this:

```
<a id='testOne'>One</a>
```

and this javascript:

```
//To remove the title and default action.
$("#testOne").attr("title", "").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}).attr("onclick", null);

//To reset the title and action
$("#testOne").attr("title", "Test One").click(function(e){
  doTest('one');
});
```

But when my link (that's styled like a button) is reset then the cursor is a crosshair and not a pointer. I checked and it is set to `auto`. Is there some way I can set this to a pointer?

Comment: What do you have the link for if it does not link anywhere?

Comment: You mean `$( "#testOne" )` not `$( "testOne" )`.

Answer (score 10):

That is because you dont have href attribute in a anchor tag. Try this

```
<a id='testOne' href="#">One</a>
```

Or

```
<a id='testOne' href="javascript:void(0);">One</a>
```

Comment: You dont need css to show a pointer for an anchor tag, just set the href attribute as shown above you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can set style of any item by `.css` property 
Try this

```
  $("#testOne").css("cursor","pointer");
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest ,whatever you are try to do is tough to understand. You can try this

change anchor tag `<a id='testOne' href='javascript:'>One</a>`

or

in your css class  add following

```
cursor:poitner
```